# python 2 division

Tags: python, division, python-2.x

```
#this works in python 3
def pi_sum(n):
    total, k = 0,1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total +8 /(k *(k+2)), k + 4
    return total

#this is how i tried to fix it for python 2
def pi_sum2(n):
    total, k = 0,1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = float(total +8) /(k *(k+2)), k + 4
    return total
```

In python 2: for `pi_sum2(1e6)` I get `8.000032000112001e-12`.  What's wrong here?

**EDIT** above my first mistake was applying float to both total and 8..
i should have done:

```
#this is how i tried to fix it for python 2
def pi_sum2(n):
    total, k = 0,1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + float(8) /(k *(k+2)), k + 4
    return total
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `float(total) + 8 / (k *(k+2))` ?

Comment: oops close, but i figured out it should actually should be total + float(8)/(k*(k+2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your variables explicitly as floats to avoid some type coersion:

```
def pi_sum(n):
    total, k = 0.0, 1.0
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + 8.0 /(k *(k+2)), k + 4
    return total
```

should do the trick

Comment: this works, but i also edited the statement to show how it can be done using float()

Comment: you could use `8.0` instead of going through a function lookup to call `float(8)`

Comment: It should be enough to do `total, k = 0.0, 1` as only `total` is used as a float.

Comment: Besides, wit ould be more readable to do `total += 8.0 /(k *(k+2))` and `k += 4` separately. IMHO.